# Viz.js: Change border color of a shape

Tags: javascript, svg, graphviz

I have the following DOT script for Viz.js:

```
digraph G {
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        color=red;
        node [style=filled, color=grey];
        b0 -> b1 ;
        label = "process #2";
    }
    start -> b0;
    start [shape=Mdiamond];
}
```

I want to change the border of shape `b0`. In the documentation there is a property color.border, but I could not insert it in this context without getting a bug. How can I change the color of the border e.g. to blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `color` and `fillcolor`. If `fillcolor` isn't provided, the fill defaults to the `color` value, so the border and fill are the same.

Here's one way to do it for your example:

```
digraph G {
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        color=red;
        node [style=filled, color=grey];
        b0 [color=blue, fillcolor=grey]
        b0 -> b1 ;
        label = "process #2";
    }
    start -> b0;
    start [shape=Mdiamond];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. :) Is there a documentation explaining that? I could not find anything

Comment: @CodePope - it's sorta mentioned in the documentation for the [fillcolor](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fillcolor) attribute, but it could be more clear: "Color used to fill the background of a node or cluster assuming style=filled, or a filled arrowhead. If fillcolor is not defined, color is used."